# Contact from include BCC along with Recipient

Tags: php, contact-form, bcc

I want to send BCC email along with Recipient in Contact form. How I can include BCC in my code? I am not seeing error in below code but it won't send you email to BCC or Recipient. If I remove BCC, it will send you to Recipient.

```
 $recipient = "xjkfak223@gmail.com";   

// Set the email subject.
$subject = "New contact from $name";

// Build the email content.
$email_content = "Name:  $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email:  $email\n\n";
$email_content .= "Phone:  $phone\n\n";
$email_content .= "Message:  $message\n";
$email_content .= "$subscribe: Yes\n";

// Build the email headers.
$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
$email_headers = "BCC: xy123@gmail.com";

// Send the email.
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
    // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Thank You for Contacting Us.";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181025/php-mail-adding-bcc ?

Comment: It might be easier if you actually used PHPMailer instead of incorrectly tagging your question with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Mail adding BCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181025/php-mail-adding-bcc)

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the variable.
If you add `.=` it will append the string. I suppose you need a <s>comma</s> new line between too.

```
$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>\n";
$email_headers .= "BCC: xy123@gmail.com";
```